tRPC - nextjs - app router - build fail on timeout error when using useSuspenseQuery
I created T3-app and my build fail on timeout error.
If I change this line:
const [leads] = api.lead.getLeads.useSuspenseQuery();

to
const { data: leads } = api.lead.getLeads.useQuery();

the build pass.
How can I use useSuspenceQuery?
What am I doing wrong?
Besides not having a loading/error state, is there any other benefit of suspenceQuery?
the complete error:
Failed to build /page: / (attempt 1 of 3) because it took more than 60 seconds. Retrying again shortly.
Failed to build /page: / (attempt 2 of 3) because it took more than 60 seconds. Retrying again shortly.
Failed to build /page: / after 3 attempts.
Export encountered an error on /page: /, exiting the build.
 ⨯ Static worker exited with code: 1 and signal: null

this is the page component:
import { api, HydrateClient } from "@/trpc/server";
import { Leads } from "./_components/Leads/Leads";

export default async function Home() {
  await api.lead.getLeads.prefetch();

  return (
    <HydrateClient>
      <Leads />
    </HydrateClient>
  );
}


This is the leads table component where the useSuspenseQuery is at:
"use client";

import { api } from "@/trpc/react";
import { Table } from "../../UI";
import { columns } from "./LeadsTable.columns";

export const LeadsTable = () => {
  const [leads] = api.lead.getLeads.useSuspenseQuery();

  return (
    <Table
      rows={leads}
      columns={columns}
      initialState={{
        sorting: {
          sortModel: [
            {
              field: "id",
              sort: "desc",
            },
          ],
        },
      }}
    />
  );
};


This is the entire repo: https://github.com/ItayTur/sohnim-io-ui/settings
